# How do I decrypt my files from WannaCry?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, encryption, malware, wannacrypt

So you see, my files got encrypted by WannaCry while I was testing it on VM. I accidentally left a shared folder on (which means so much to me) and it got encrypted. Please help! I was using a Windows XP Profesional SP3 x86 in the VM. I was using VirtualBox. My host PC is Windows 10 Pro x64.

Edit: Some files were not encrypted. (on the Shared Folder)
Edit: I already restarted it. (meaning I can't use wanakiwi.)

Comment: Look at this site to see if there is a solution for your case: nomoreransom.org

Comment: I'll try it later.

Comment: Unfortunately, No More Ransom did no use. :(

Answer (score 2):

For Windows XP, several tools exist for decrypting WannaCry encrypted
files.
The requirements for success vary according to your setup and the
XP service-pack version.

Here are the tools that I found:

- [Trend Micro Ransomware File Decryptor](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1114221-downloading-and-using-the-trend-micro-ransomware-file-decryptor)
- [Wannakey](https://github.com/aguinet/wannakey)
- [wanakiwi](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/wanakiwi)

Note carefully the conditions of each tool for successfully decrypting
the files.

Comment: I tried wanakiwi but since I restarted the VM, it didn't work.

Comment: I also tried Trend Micro and it was useless.

Comment: I'll try Wannakey later.

Comment: As I warned, there are very strict conditions for success. The operation should be done in the infected computer (VM in your case). Good luck!